# adding to document.cookie not working

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to run the bellow code in the chrome javascript compiler (Chrome Settings->Tools->Javascript Console)

```
document.cookie = "otac_auth_code=; Max-Age=0; Expires=Mon, 14-Apr-2014 15:25:09 GMT; Domain=.o2.co.uk; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly;";
```

however if i then run

```
document.cookie
```

the output is "", why is this and how can I make the first line of code work properly?

Comment: If you want to delete a cookie, go to Resources -> Cookie -> <your domain name> -> <Cookie> -> Right-click -> Delete.

Comment: I dont want to delete any cookies, i want to add a cookie

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update or save "HttpOnly" cookie via javascript on client side.  This can only be done from the server side code.

Comment: i took your advice and tried this instead, document.cookie = "otac_auth_code=; Max-Age=0; Expires=Mon, 14-Apr-2014 15:25:09 GMT; Domain=.o2.co.uk; Path=/; Secure;"; but still the document.cookie object is not accepting it

Comment: Probably because you are setting Max-Age=0.   that means it not valid.  Try removing that and see if it works.

Comment: Nope still nothing, this is what i tried document.cookie = "otac_auth_code=; Expires=Mon, 14-Apr-2014 15:25:09 GMT; Domain=.o2.co.uk; Path=/; Secure;";

Comment: Here is what i did and it seems to work.  document.cookie = "otac_auth_code=; Expires=Mon, 16-Apr-2014 15:25:09 GMT; Path=/;"  I couldn't use domain since I was on my local machine.

Comment: when you specify a domain, then the cookie will only be visible when you are on that domain. refer to this excellent article on javascript and cookies. http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-and-cookies/